# How to fix this error when using Live Server extension in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/iframe_handler.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/content.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I had almost exactly the same problem:

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/sourcemaps/onloadwff.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"

It indicated in the error it has something to do with Chrome extensions, so I went into my extensions and searched (Ctrl-F) for a small snippet of the error text, `hdokiejnpimake`. It found that **LastPass: Free Password Manager 4.47.0** was the problem. I disabled it and the error went away.